# How to set global environment in csh and ksh?

Tags: ksh, csh

**ksh**
`export name="bhargav"`

**csh** `setenv name bhargav`

Trying like this and from windows Iam using plink command to get the variable value. But it showing the error **undefined variable**

Comment: Post the full command-line you are using for plink. For the user-account on the target unix hostname, its shell startup file(s) for that user needs to define any variables you might want.

Comment: In Linux .kshrc `export name="bhargav"`, In windows plink command is `plink -pw password ec2-user@10.0.0.0 "echo $name"`

Answer (score 0):

For the target-user, does Linux have bash or ksh as the shell for that user? If Linux is configured with bash as the shell, then ensure that the ~/.bashrc exports that variable. If Linux is configured with ksh as the shell for the user account (instead of bash), try exporting the variable in ~/.profile

Comment: Iam using ksh. $0 is showing -ksh. When I am executing plink command from windows `plink -pw password ec2-user@10.0.0.0 "echo $0" `  output is <b>-ksh</b>

Comment: So plink does not invoke the shell startup, which is the reason your variable is not initialized .    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407386/plink-does-not-source-bashrc-or-bash-profile-on-connect